# Found a path in an adjacency matrix

Tags: java, matrix, adjacency-matrix

I am trying to find a path in an adjacency matrix but I always get this error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4
    at GraphApp.main(GraphApp.java:102)
```

Here is my code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < adjMat.length; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < adjMat[i].length; j++)
        if (i < j)
            if (adjMat[i][j] == 1) //
                for (i = j + 1; i < adjMat.length; i++)
                    if (adjMat[i][j] == 1)
                        System.out.println("Graph conatains a path");
                    else
                        System.out.println("Graph doesn't contain a path");
```

When I have, for example, a matrix like this:

```
0 1 1 1
1 0 1 0
1 1 0 0
1 0 0 0
```

I should verify if, for example, the `1`in `T[0][1]` has another `1` in `T[i][1]` except the first one of course because the matrix is symmetric.

Comment: Please, no one-liner `if`'s and `for`'s; put braces around them. Otherwise it's extremely hard to read and frustrating bugs can easily sneak in.

Answer (score 4):

You are using `i` two times in your loops could cause ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. If you use correct braces it will help to read your code easily and find out the problem.

```
for (int i = 0; i < adjMat.length; i++) // first 
 ...
    ...
       for (i = j + 1; i < adjMat.length; i++)  // second
```